# Normalizing too much vs too little, examples?

Tags: database, schema, normalization, denormalization

I don't usually design databases, so I'm having some doubts about how to normalize (or not) a table for registering users. The fields I'm having doubts are:

- locationTown: I plan to normalize for countries, and have a separate table for it, but should I do the same for towns? I guess users would type this in when registering, and not choosing from a dropdown. Can one normalize when the input may be coming from users?
- maritalStatus: I would have a choice of about 5 or so different statuses.

Also, does anyone know of a good place to find real world database schema/normalizing examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `locationTown` - just store it directly inside user table. Otherwise you will have to search for existing town, taking typos and code case into account. Also some people use non-standard characters and languages (Kraków vs. Krakow vs. Cracow, see also: [romanization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization)). If you really want to have a table with towns, at least provide auto-complete box so the users are more likely choosing existing town. Otherwise prepare for lots of duplicates or almost duplicates.
- `maritalStatus` - this in the other hand should be in a separate table. Or more accurately: use single character or a number to represent marital status. An extra table mapping this to human-readable form is just for convenience (remember about [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n)) and foreign key constraint makes sure incorrect status aren't used.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't worry about it too much - database normalization (3NF, et al) has been [over-emphasized in academia and isn't overly practical in industry](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html). In addition, we would need to see your whole schema in order to judge where these implementations are appropriate. Focus on indexing commonly-used columns before you worry about normalization.

You might want to take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173066/is-database-normalization-still-necessary) before you dive in any further.